# Linking Ruby Interpreter into C program

Tags: c, ruby, api, interpreter

I'm trying to include the Ruby interpreter in a C program. I'v been using this link as a guide: https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/embed/#startup-teardown.

I have the following code in C:

```c
#include <ruby.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* construct the VM */
    ruby_init();

    // puts "hola"
    /* Ruby goes here */

    /* destruct the VM */
    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}
```

The problem is when I try to compile the code, I get the following message:

reference to **ruby_init** undefined

reference to **ruby_cleanup** undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with `libruby`, as noted in the link:

> Embedding Ruby requires one header `ruby.h`, which includes a platform-specific header `ruby/config.h`. You will probably need to tell your compiler about the include paths for these headers. You will also need to link with the Ruby lib. On my machine, my minimal compiler options are
>
> ```
> $ gcc -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -lruby
> ```
>
> Though, if available, you should really use pkg-config to get the appropriate options for your distribution:
>
> ```
> $ pkg-config --cflags --libs ruby-2.5
> ```

Combining these two, you get `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs ruby-2.5) <files> <libs>`.

Comment: JL2210 I tried to do that but i have the following message: Package ruby-2.5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `ruby-2.5.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Comment: @ErickPro What version of Ruby do you have installed? Do you have the development package installed?

Comment: I have ruby 2.5.5, i made the installation with rvm but how can i know if i have the development package? I'm pretty new in Linux, sorry.